# Mongo's Java driver, how to build a complex query

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I'm testing against a database with one document in it. With the following code I get the following result from the database

```
BasicDBObject keys = new BasicDBObject();
keys.put("symbol", 1 );
keys.put("price", 1 );
keys.put("Exchange", "SH");
keys.put("NumShares", new BasicDBObject("$gte", 0) );

BasicDBObject empty = new BasicDBObject();

DBCursor cursor_02 = coll_tmp.find( empty, keys );
System.out.println( "<2> " + cursor_02.count());
while(cursor_02.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println( "<2>  " + cursor_02.next());
}
```

This will print out the following data

```
<2>  { <id & oid> , "symbol" : "ESLR" , "Exchange" : "SH"}
```

The document also has a "NumShares" field set to a value of 2.34508872. Wanting to try out the $gt, $gte, $lt, $lte, and $ne operators, I add in a line of code after the last 'keys.put()' line.

```
keys.put("Price", new BasicDBObject("$gte", 0) );
```

This code should continue to select the lone document, as it's NumShares field is indeed greater than or equal to zero. Instead I get the following error.

```
Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: NumShares: { $gte: 0 }
```

The goal ultimately is to have a MongoDB equivalent of the SQL query "SELECT price, symbol, exhange FROM stock WHERE NumShares >= 0, etc..."

I realize that [mkyong doesn't cover this particular query structure in his tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-query-document/), so I'm asking you all. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your result-restricting query arguments to your first Object of the query. The second Object is a Projection of the result. It can only specify the tags to be displayed (as true/1 or false/0) there are no other restrictions like "$lte" allowed. Putting it to the query object like in the following should work:

```
BasicDBObject keys = new BasicDBObject();
keys.put("symbol", 1 );
keys.put("price", 1 );
keys.put("Exchange", 1);

BasicDBObject search = new BasicDBObject();
search.put("Exchange", "SH");
search.put("numShares", new BasicDBObject("$gte", 0) );

DBCursor cursor_02 = coll_tmp.find(search, keys);
```

Also MongoDBs keys of documents are case-sensitive. So if your key is "NumShares" you cannot find it by looking for "numShares".

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation, I couldn't find that anywhere

Answer (score 3):

You want to put your criteria in the query, not in the list of keys you want to return:

```
BasicDBObject keys = new BasicDBObject(); // will specify the returned fields (SELECT)
keys.put("symbol", 1 );
keys.put("price", 1 );
keys.put("Exchange", 1);

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(); // will select the documents you want (WHERE)
query.put("numShares", new BasicDBObject("$gte", 0) ); 

DBCursor cursor_02 = coll_tmp.find( query, keys );
System.out.println( "<2> " + cursor_02.count());
while(cursor_02.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println( "<2>  " + cursor_02.next());
}
```